# JavaScript "this" getAttribute for button onclick

Tags: javascript, getattribute

The following snippet of code works in an array for passing the "index" attribute whose value is "i"  to a button onclick function :

```
    button.setAttribute('index',i);
     button.setAttribute('onclick','getProductInfo(this.getAttribute("index"))');
```

What I want to do is create a var that will getAttribute of a particular "this" index such as:

```
      button.setAttribute('index',i);
      var thisIndex= button.getAttribute(this.index);
      button.setAttribute('onclick','getProductInfo(thisIndex))'
```

An extra redundant step but I would like to know how to go about this? 
Any ideas

Comment: `button.setAttribute('onclick','getProductInfo(' + thisIndex + '))'`

Comment: thanks!  how would I call it in a function?  getProductinfo(index) ?

Comment: can you make it clear ?

Comment: I mean how would you call the getProductInfo  function ?

Answer (score 0):

use string concatenation

```
button.setAttribute('index',i);
var thisIndex= button.getAttribute(this.index);
button.setAttribute('onclick','getProductInfo('+thisIndex+'))';
```

Comment: Thanks. I considered that but  quite didn't understand why  string concatenation works  ' +thisIndex '.  Can you please guide me why it works?

Comment: In `getProductInfo` method you need to pass correct value, when you cancatenate `thisIndex`, the value of `thisIndex` is passed, but if you write `'getProductInfo(thisIndex))'`, it will pass thisIndex as a string (which does not contain the index, rather string value 'thisIndex') not the index